# Should Javascript's "for in" construct iterate the length property?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, for-in-loop

I'm making a bookmarklet, but I've encountered some wierd behaviour in IE8. The code causing the problem is this:

```
var els = document.getElementById("my_id").getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i in els)
{
    alert(i+","+els[i])
}
```

The first thing that is alerted is "length, n". This isn't the case in chrome: just in IE8.

Interestingly, it seems to behave differently depending on whether the code goes in the console/address bar or the page itself.

Is this standard behaviour?

#### EDIT:

Not down to the website that I run it on either. Is it possible that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array with a `"length"` key set in IE? It certainly doesn't return a pure array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get is not an array, it is a nodeList.
See [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstructure), click the link "getElementsByTagName('element_name')"

Furthermore, for..in is not meant to be used for iterating over an array anyway. Use

```
var item;
for (var idx=0, len=arr.length; idx<len; ++idx) {
  item = arr[idx];
  // whatever
}
```

for array iteration.

For a nodelist, you can get the element with

```
list.item(idx); // where list is what you got from getElementsByTagName
```

if you want to do it "right".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `idx++` instead of `++idx`.  Otherwise you miss the first element.

Comment: No, that's fine. `idx` is 0 until the *last* part of the for-expression is evaluated. Which is `++idx`.
Here's the order:  
1: `var idx=0, len=arr.length`  
2: `idx<len`  
3: {code of the body}  
4: `++i`  

So `++idx` or `idx++` doesn't matter for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying ;) I guess I am just so used to seeing i++ that this looked foreign to me!

Comment: In fact ++idx is slightly better because it updates idx. idx++ clones idx. In practice though it probably doesn't matter much

Answer (score 2):

The IE behavior is correct. It may return all kinds of weird stuff, since `for .. in` iterates over all member names of the object.

`getElementsByTagName` returns a **`NodeList`**, and the properties of a `NodeList` are specified in the [DOM standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177): `length` and `item(i)`. Most JavaScript implementations will also allow `[i]`.

Therefore, you should write the following:

```
var els = document.getElementById("my_id").getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0;i < els.length;i++)
{
    alert(i+","+els.item(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `for..in` for anything other than enumerating properties of an object (unless you like surprises!) Just use a simple for loop for arrays and nodelists.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I iterate over lists. This way, you won't have to write an extra line in the loop, such as `var el = els[i]`.

```
var els = document.getElementById("my_id").getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, el; el=els[i]; i++) {
    // do what you like here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you define your own iterator for `NodeList`s, which is JavaScript (Mozilla)-only. [Here's an implementation] of one I have created for my js-iterators repo.

Answer (score 0):

A method to convert an object, like a node list, arguments object, or custom object to an array of its members is often useful.

```
Array.from= function(what){
 var L, A= [];
 if(!what) what= {};
 L= what.length;
 if(typeof L== 'number'){
  while(L) A[--L]= what[L];
  return A;
 }
 for(var p in what){
  if(what.hasOwnProperty(p)) A[A.length]= what[p];
 }
 return A;
}

var N=Array.from(document.getElementById("my_id").getElementsByTagName("*"))
while(N.length){
tem=N.shift();
}
```